# Extrair últimos números com Regex

Tags: java, regex

Tenho estes dois exemplos de *strings*:

```
/news/uk-news/commuter-who-extraordinary-row-woman-12345
/news/weird/dude-who-killed-14-extraordinary-98765.amp
```

Quero pegar apenas os últimos números, `12345` e `98765`, respectivamente.

No meio da string, podem haver outros números. E no final, podem ter outros caracteres (ou não) que não sejam números. O que eu gostaria mesmo era os últimos números, após o último hífen `-`.

Tentei com `(\w+-)(\d+)(\W*)`, mas retornou apenas uma parte. Alguém pode, por favor, me ajudar com uma solução correta?

Comment: resolveu! Muito obrigado!

Comment: esse negocio dos lookaround é potente!

Comment: rs.. verdade. Facilita bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este `regex` irá pegar apenas a última sequência numérica (ou apenas o último número) da string:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

Exemplos:

```
/news/uk-news/commuter-who-extraordinary-row-woman-12345
// retorna 12345

/news/weird/dude-who-killed-14-extraordinary-98765.amp
// retorna 98765

/qualquer15coisa-20.-s10.amp
// retorna 10

foo.1.10.foo
// retorna 10
```